# How to distinguished an AD object

Tags: active-directory, attributes

In our firm we have a lot of consultants. All our consultants is placed in a OU called `consultants`. Years have past and in those years we have created AD account that is a "shared" account. This account is used for more than 1 person, because we have night shifts. I need to find a solution that distinguishes the shared account from the consultants.

So my question is, about the AD attribute: `objectClass`. When you create an AD account these `(top, person, organizationalPerson, user)` are added to the `objectClass` as standard. I can see I can add other text to the `objectClass`.

Maybe my question is stupid, but if I add a text for example `shared`, will that be deleted by AD or is this the way to accomplish my goal?

Thank you in advance.

/Kenneth

Comment: The `objectClass` describes the **type** of the object - it's a system attribute, and you should **not** mess around with it! I would recommend using something else (a purely "Informational" string attribute) - like `Department` or something like that.

Comment: If the recommendation is not to mess around with it, why is there an option to add text of free choice?

Answer (score 0):

The objectClass attribute is an important one in AD. The values put there must exist in the schema. So you cannot add just any value there.

But there are other attributes you might be able to use, for example:

- description
- info (called "Notes" under the Telephone tab in Users and Computers)
- comment
- employeeType